# Autolayout - How to keep an UIImageView fixed in a corner

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout, uilabel

I'm struggling with a custom UITableViewCell which displays an UIImage view on the left side and three UILabel elements.

[image: Custom UITableViewCell]

I'm using Autolayout to keep all the components aligned and it works ok when the labels have one line, but since the one with `Lorem ipsum dolor` and the one with `Ut enim ad minim veniam.` labels should support multiple lines, I need to place the image in the cell following a criteria.

I was thinking about centering it **or** trying to fix it on the left top of the cell (something like facebook messenger does with the avatar icons and messages).

Centered UIImageView
[image: Centered UIImageView]

Top UIImageview
[image: Top UIImageView]

Is it possible by using Autolayout constraints in storyboard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sure, just pin it to the top or center in container.

Comment: Both is possible with Auto Layout in Interface Builder.